# Refresh-frequency-calculation's start date for a full sandbox

Tags: sandbox-refresh

This will take me 29 days to test, hence asking the following question.

Context: You can refresh a Full sandbox every 29 days.

Question: Will I be able to see the refresh hyperlink for a full sandbox:

1. 28 days after clicking <kbd>Refresh</kbd>, or
2. 28 days after receiving the **Refresh Complete** email, or
3. 28 days after clicking <kbd>Activate</kbd>, or
4. 28 days after receiving the **Activation Complete** email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer is 2.

### The 29 days will be calculated from the day the you receive the refresh complete email.

*Source: Salesforce Premier+ Support.*

Comment: allright, didn't know that. Tnx for pointing out..